#  how can I find zooming factor of UIImageView inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

What is the most easiest way to find the zooming factor when I zoom in/out the UIImageView inside the scroll view? I know maybe I can do some calculation on the scrollViewDidZoom delegate, but is there an easier way? I know there's also `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale`, but this is only after the zoom ends, not while it's at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has a [`zoomScale` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW41), which sounds like what you want: "A floating-point value that specifies the current scale factor applied to the scroll view's content."